# ACTION_VIEW for images but only a subset of images

Tags: android, image, android-intent, actionview

I have an app that have more than one gallery. It is a travel app and it have a separate gallery for each trip. When I'm taking pictures with the camera I'm saving them in the default MediaStore of the system.

To view an Image I'm using `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)` and it launches the default image viewer. When scrolling with the left and right arrows it displays all the pictures in the folder where the pictures from the camera are saved.

Is there any way to put an extra in the intent when calling VIEW action which images to scroll trough? I have the IDs of the images for a certain trip in a database.

Or putting them in  a separate folder is the only solution?

Comment: Too late to comment. But _scrolling with the left and right arrows it displays all the pictures in the folder_ Can you please tell how did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider building your own preview activity using a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html). Of course this is more work to do, but also offers more flexibility:

- You can create "virtual" folders
- You can display images from local store or from the net (if you want to offer synchronization with web albums for example)
- You can highlight certain images (favorite, shared)